# The ImageField attribute has no file associated with it, can't figure out why

Tags: python, django, qr-code

So I am trying to generate a QR code on creation of the Device Model and save it to the device model, for some reason even though I can generate the image, I can't save it to the model.

I've tried saving with a filebuffer instead, that gave me an error, I just don't know what else to try.

The error is The 'qrcode' attribute has no file associated with it.

```
def Device(models.Model):
  qrcode = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="qrcode")

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.generate_qrcode()
    super(Device, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def generate_qrcode(self):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=6,
        border=0,
    )
    qr.add_data("http://localhost/ims/device/" + str(self.id))
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image()

    filename = str(self.id) + '.jpg'

    img.save(filename)
```

Comment: You need to assign the generated qrcode to you instance `qrcode`, e.g. something like `self.qrcode = File(img, filename)` instead of `img.save(...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a generated PIL image into an ImageField in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064705/save-a-generated-pil-image-into-an-imagefield-in-django)