# 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed' while generating Qr code from model

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models
import qrcode
```

model

```
# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    registerd_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/static/images/",blank=True,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

function take data and convert to qr code and save to model field data

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.Image=qrcode.make(self.name)
       super(Customer,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064705/save-a-generated-pil-image-into-an-imagefield-in-django  try this

Answer (score 0):

## one of ways to solve it:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.Image:
        from tempfile import TemporaryFile
        from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
        from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
        from django.utils.encoding import force_text
        import qrcode
        with TemporaryFile() as f:
            img = qrcode.make(self.name)
            img.save(f)
            f.seek(0)
            self.Image = default_storage.save(force_text("%s.png"%self.name), 
                ContentFile(f.read()))
    super(Customer,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```